# Animation is not playing after i animated material, also animator gets disabled when i play animation clip

Tags: unity, animation, materials

Here have a look at this screen recording (https://youtu.be/PvAt_t0NdQk). What am I doing wrong?
I have selected prefab and working on it directly. I animated the material of the object I want it to fade out, so I animated the material and it works but then it doesn't after I unclick from it. Also, I have noticed the Animator component is getting disabled when I play the animation clip.

Comment: From the video it looks like your alpha is being animated when you press play are you sure the problem is with animation and not with material.

Comment: As it stands, it's difficult for a reader of this question to have any idea what you're trying to do, how you've done it, and where it went wrong from reading your text. All that information depends on the video. Users usually only click video links for questions they're already pretty confident they can help with, so this will tend to lower your click-through rates and make it harder to get answers. It also makes the question less searchable, so other users with similar issues are less likely to find it. I recommend editing your question to include a complete description here in the text too.